# Weighted View in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to add a `PlotView` (custom View) into a `LinearLayout`. My `LinearLayout` has a `weightSum` of 8. Inside my .xml I defined a `Space` (weight of 3) that has to appear above my `PlotView` and a `Button` (weight of 1) that should follow my plot underneath. So far, so good.
Now the `PlotView` is added programmatically, with a weight of 4. However, it will always consume almost the entire screen, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

My Code:

1. *main_activity.xml (snippet)*

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:id="@+id/linlayout"
       android:weightSum="8">

       <Space
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_weight="3"/>

       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/calibrate"
           android:id="@+id/calibration"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. *main_activity.java (snippet)*

   ```
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlayout);
   plotView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4f));
   layout.addView(plotView, 1);
   ```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the height, which is affected by the weight, to 0.

Code in `.xml`:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Code in `.java`:

```
plotView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 4f));
```